# How to update the updateAuthority of an NFT

Tags: metaplex

good afternoon everyone! I'm having trouble finding docs / examples on how to change the updateAuthority of a mint address.

would someone be able to point me in the right direction / help out here?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Helo, if you were using `sugar` to create a CandyMachine and want to update the Authority for all the unminted NFTs on your CandyMachine you just have to use `sugar update --new-authority <NEW_AUTHORITY_PUBKEY>`. This will update all the unminted NFTs authority (when they get minted will have the new authority). If you do this, make sure to update the collection NFT update authority to avoid problems while minting.

If you want to update the authority for an already minted NFT, you have to use [metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/set.html#set-update-authority).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! So I have looked at metaboss, and it looks like it requires the config file for the NFT.

In my case, I have 600+ NFTs with the updateAuthority set to my address and I do not have the config for any of them.

Comment: You have to create it, it's an easy script that you can code. You can also have the ids of your NFTs with metaboss and you just have to replace the uri

Answer (score 1):

you can change the mint authority using

```
let cpi_accounts = SetAuthority {
    account_or_mint: self.nft_mint.to_account_info().clone(),
    current_authority: self.current_authority.to_account_info().clone(),
 };
let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(
                      self.token_program.to_account_info().clone(), 
                      cpi_accounts
                   );
    
anchor_spl::token::set_authority(
    cpi_ctx,
    AuthorityType::MintTokens,
    Some(new_authority),
  )
    .expect("set_authority failed");
```